ARM Assembler. Программа для умножения в дополнительном коде
Я студент и в ассемблере полный 0, GPT не помогает((
Нужна программа которая реализует Умножение целых чисел со знаком в дополнительном коде с неподвижной суммой частичных произведений, сдвигом множимого вправо и анализом множителя, начиная со старших разрядов с предварительным изменением знака.
Если по пунктам то необходимо ввести числа в 10й с/с, преобразовать их в дополнительный код. После преобразования в дк необходимо ещё раз преобразовать их в дк (сделать инверсию и добавить 1 к младшему разряду). После этих манипуляций необходимо провести умножение путем перемножения каждого разряда множителя на множимое со сдвигом вправо,провести сложение промежуточных произведений и вывести результат в один из регистров.
Если кто-то сможет с этим помочь, буду благодарен.
Вот код который смог сделать Chat GPT
`.global _start
.section .data
A:  .word 10   @ Пример значения числа A (замените на свое значение)
B:  .word -5   @ Пример значения числа B (замените на свое значение)
ResultA: .space 4 @ Результат конвертации числа A
ResultB: .space 4 @ Результат конвертации числа B
.section .text
_start:
@ Преобразование числа A в дополнительный код
ldr r0, =A
ldr r1, [r0]
mvn r2, r1
add r2, r2, #1
str r2, [r0]
@ Преобразование числа B в дополнительный код
ldr r0, =B
ldr r1, [r0]
mvn r2, r1
add r2, r2, #1
str r2, [r0]

@ Умножение A на B
ldr r0, =A    @ Загрузка A в r0
ldr r1, =B    @ Загрузка B в r1
ldr r2, [r1]  @ Загрузка значения B в r2
ldr r3, [r0]  @ Загрузка значения A в r3
mov r4, #0    @ Инициализация счетчика цикла
mov r5, #0    @ Инициализация переменной для хранения результата

multiply_loop:
cmp r2, #0    @ Проверка на конец множителя
beq multiply_done @ Если множитель равен нулю, завершить умножение
and r6, r2, #1  @ Получение младшего бита множителя
cmp r6, #1      @ Проверка младшего бита
beq add_A_to_result  @ Если младший бит равен 1, прибавить A к результату

add r3, r3, r3 @ Сдвиг A влево (умножение на 2)
add r2, r2, r2 @ Сдвиг множителя влево (деление на 2)
b multiply_loop @ Переход к следующей итерации цикла

add_A_to_result:
add r5, r5, r3 @ Прибавление A к результату
add r3, r3, r3 @ Сдвиг A влево (умножение на 2)
add r2, r2, r2 @ Сдвиг множителя влево (деление на 2)
b multiply_loop @ Переход к следующей итерации цикла
multiply_done:
@ Теперь r5 содержит результат умножения A на B
@ Можно выполнить необходимые операции с результатом здесь
@ Например, можно сохранить результат в памяти или вывести на экран
@ Завершение программы
swi 0         @ Вызов прерывания программного обеспечения для завершения программы

`
